# Substitution into second order O.D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have been given the task to solve:

$$x^2 \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+ 4y = 0$$

and also given the substitution $x = e^u$.

My detailed working is below but my question is about a few steps in the process of substitution. I know what to do, and it "works", but I don't understand why what I am doing is valid. Can someone explain?

From steps $R2.1, R2.2$ in the detail below I get:

\begin{align}\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) &= {\dfrac{du}{dx}}.\dfrac{d}{du}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) \tag{R2.1}\\
&=\dfrac{d}{du}(\dfrac{dy}{du}).\dfrac{du}{dx} \tag{R2.2} \end{align}

Can someone explain why that is valid?

Working

$x = e^u$ so $$\dfrac{dx}{du} = e^u = x  $$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du}.\dfrac{du}{dx} =  \dfrac{dy}{du}.\dfrac{1}{x}$$

Therefore $x\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du}\tag{1}$

Differentiating again, $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x\dfrac{dy}{dx}) = \dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) \tag{2}$$

LHS of $(2)$ is

$$x \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \dfrac{dy}{dx}\tag{(L)}$$

and RHS of  $(2)$

\begin{align}\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) &= {\dfrac{du}{dx}}.\dfrac{d}{du}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) \tag{R2.1}\\
&=\dfrac{d}{du}(\dfrac{dy}{du}).\dfrac{du}{dx} \tag{R2.2} \\
&= \dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}.\dfrac{du}{dx} =\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}.\dfrac{1}{x} \tag{R2.3} \end{align}

To finish the substitution

$$(L) = (R2.3)$$

$$x \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}.\dfrac{1}{x}$$

so

$$x^2 \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}$$

then adding multiples of $(1)$

$$x^2 \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\dfrac{dy}{dx} + 5(x\dfrac{dy}{dx} ) +4y =\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}+ 5 \dfrac{dy}{du} + 4y$$

which can be solved by usual methods, finally back-substituting $u = \ln x$

Comment: Hello Siong can you explain why you changed the "latex tags" in my original post from "\$" to "\$\$" ? I can't tell the difference in appearance of the edited post from the original post. In what sense does your edit improve readability of the post? I wish like to understand this to "improve" the presentation of the content for when I write posts.

Answer (score 0):

> RHS (2)
>
> $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) = {\dfrac{du}{dx}}.\dfrac{d}{du}(\dfrac{dy}{du}) =$  (R2.1)
>
> = $\dfrac{d}{du}(\dfrac{dy}{du}).\dfrac{du}{dx} =$  (R2.2)
>
> = $\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}.\dfrac{du}{dx} =\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}.\dfrac{1}{x}$  (R2.3)

Perhaps it's clearer like this, by the chain rule (in blue):
$$\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx}}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right) = \color{blue}{\frac{d}{du}\frac{du}{dx}}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right)$$
And then with $\color{red}{\tfrac{du}{dx}=\tfrac{1}{x}}$, you have:
$$\frac{d}{du}\color{red}{\frac{du}{dx}}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right)=
\color{red}{\frac{du}{dx}}\frac{d}{du}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right) =
\color{red}{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{d^2y}{du^2}  $$